# How to receive state in App Bar using bloc

Tags: flutter

I have an list view Builder in scaffold widget. I need to count list size and display list size in App Bar. I can't get state in APP Bar using bloc pattern. I can get state except App Bar. How  can i get and change state in App Bar using Bloc Pattern.

Comment: Why can't you get the state in your `AppBar`? Just wrap your `Scaffold` in a `StreamBuilder`.

Comment: I am using bloc builder to change state.  I have written bloc builder with in scaffold widget.

Comment: Yes but you can just move your Scaffold widget so it is within the bloc builder.

Comment: Could you please explain me how can i do that.

Comment: If you update your question to include some code, I'll try and show you.

Comment: @JordanDavies it's bad idea, because it will cause redraw of whole screen for every state change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put a listener on your `List`; fyi...  this is a feature built into `Streambuilder` or `ListView.builder` and perform `setState((){ publicInt = list.length})`.  Instantiate a public `int` variable of `publicInt` that will update every time `list.length` changes and add it to your AppBar title.  Similar to the code below...

```
int publicInt;

 @override
  Widget build (BuildContext ctxt) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Dynamic Demo # $publicInt"),),
      body:  new ListView.builder
        (
          itemCount: litems.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
          setState((){ publicInt = list.length});
            } 
        )

      ),
    );
  }
}
```